# Split a string into 2 parts using js

Tags: javascript

I have string:

```
str= "less than some value";
```

I want to get "less than" separated from "some value", something like:

```
var a = "less than";
var b ="some value";
```

how can i do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only condition?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](//stackoverflow.com/q/96428)

Comment: What is the criteria for where to split? On the space nearest the middle, or after two words, or before the last two words, or are you saying the input will always start with the words "less than", or...?

Comment: @Tushar—I don't think that's a duplicate. The OP hasn't clearly specified how to determine where to split the string (middle character, equal words, middle space, etc.).

Comment: @RobG That's why you don't see it dupe-hammered. :)

Comment: You already did it. var a = "less than"; var b ="some value";

Comment: What is not clear about Question? "Split a string into 2 parts". While no effort was presented at text of Question as to what has been tried to solve Question, the inquiry appears clear, from perspective here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the question is kind of un-specific with it's requirements, but to get the results asked in the question I did this.

```
var word = "less than some value";
var split = word.split(" ");
var a = split[0] + " " + split[1];
var b = split[2] + " " + split[3];
console.log(a); //logged "less than"
console.log(b); //logged "some value"
```

Not exactly sure if this is what you wanted tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring method, Not much code needed and gets what you want done.

```
var str = "less than some value"; 

var somevalue = str.substring(10); // seperates string from 10 characters 
var lessthan = str.substring(0,10); // seperates string from 10 characters negative


console.log(lessthan); 
console.log(somevalue);
```

========================================================================

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/eb9c9evc/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `split` method, pass the method parameter:

```
str.split();
```